# How to make GAE+ django pick up my .po and .mo translations

Tags: django, google-app-engine, localization, locale

I got translations ready in .po and .mo files. How can I make django 1.2 display these? I can use the builtin trnanslations and now I want to enable in addition the ones I keep in [application-name]/conf/locale/[Language_Code]/LC_MESSAGES'

Is there a way? It used to work with django 0.96 and after the upgrade only the builtin translations work.

UPDATE: I tried moving to APP_DIR/locale/LANG_CODE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po and it won't work for me. Maybe I missed something. Do I have to recompile .po files?

UPDATE: Folowing the instructions here, I put my .po and .mo files in

```
APP_DIR/locale/LANG_CODE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

It still won't work. I'm considering why and welcoming any more advice or recommendation how to enable i18n features with django for google app engine.

EDIT: [Here's a link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/fae28ff10cc8bc21/2363c9a082973d74) where we discuss this issue in the GAE python group.

Update: Now it works. We didn't have to move around the directories in the conf directory. We just use:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

# Force Django to reload settings
from django.conf import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'conf.settings'
settings._target = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you locale files at:

```
APP_DIR/locale/LANG_CODE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
APP_DIR/locale/LANG_CODE/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
```

I had same problem and changing the path worked

Answer (score 1):

First you should use

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
```

in your settings file, but I think you already are aware of that. Next I suggest using `ugettext_lazy` for translation in your views (i.e. every string `'test'` in view should be passed by `ugettext_lazy('test')`). In templates using `{% trans "text" %}` should work (remember that templates need to load `{% load i18n %}`). Then use the script:

```
django-admin makemessages
```

in your `APP_DIR`. Finally edit `django.po` files and use

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

after translations. That's all. Did you tried this? Does it work or not?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But since I'm using google app engine I'm not sure whether it's completely applicable. I'll try these instructions as far as I can. I added 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
to conf/settings.py to no effect.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Somehow I did not realize that you are using GAE. :) I didn't do that in this scenario, so I guess I can't help you. Good luck, though.

Comment: We made it work doing like the updated info. Thanks for the comments.